# Modify database schema with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, erd

Using MySQL Workbench, I created an ERD and database schema.  I've deployed the database to my production server and have live data.

I now need to modify my schema.  Instead of making changes on the live server database, I would like to modify the ERD, test it, and then create a modify script to deploy on the production server.  Obviously, I do not wish to loose data, and thus cannot drop a table or column and then add new ones.

Is this possible to do with MySQL workbench?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible and it's called "Synchronization". This is a two-way merge between a model and a live database. Synchronization doesn't touch the data in the schema, but as usual, when you modify a db structure (removing tables or columns) the associated data is lost, regardless how you do that. So take care for proper backups.

[image]